# Update statement fails due to quoted identifer after adding filtered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, quoted-identifier

I just added a filtered index to an existing table, now insert/update queries don't work against this table. I've set quoted_identifier both on and off before executing my update statement, but it still fails consistently.

Note that there is no stored procedure involved here, just a naked update statement. Most answers deal with stored procedures, which is not the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is useful to anyone: it's because there's a trigger on the table with quoted_identifier OFF.